# Include a Reviews table in a database schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have 4 SQL Server tables:

**Users**

```
UserId (PK)
Name
```

**Jobs**

```
JobId (PK)
Position
```

**Candidacies**

```
CandidacyId (PK)
UserId (FK)
JobId (FK)
StatusId (FK)
```

**Statuses** (values like Hired, Standby, etc.)

```
StatusId (PK)
Name
```

A Job can have multiple Candidacies, one per User.

When a User is hired its Candidacy Status changes to Hired.

To find the User filling a job I just look for the Candidacy with Hired Status.

Any suggestion on this structure is welcome ...

**Problem**

I need to allow Users to review other Users performance on a Job.

A review would be something as follows:

```
Reviews
--------
ReviewId (PK)
Rating
Comment
```

What would be the best way to relate this Reviews to other tables knowing:

1. I need to know the User that is being reviewed;
2. I need to know the User that created the review;
3. I need to know in which job the review was made.

Comment: And thenyou need your FK to jobid, userid

Comment: You've sort of answered it yourself. Why not include reviewerId, revieweeId, and JobId as foreign keys? If you can assume that one job has one reviewer and one reviewee, your PK could be a composite of these three foreign keys.

Comment: @BarryPiccinni Yes, that is my first idea. The other was to to relat the review to candidacy since candidacy already has the job and user. but only candidacies with status equal to hired can receive reviews. So i think your suggestion is better. I was just looking for a second opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I would reference `Candidacies` from `Reviews`. In comparison with referencing `Users` and `Jobs` directly, this prevents duplication of constraints, so the schema will be cleaner. It may also have some performance advantage, as you will have smaller indexes on `Reviews` table and less FKs on `Users` and `Jobs`.

Further more, you can look at it this way: `Candidacy` with `status=Hired` is an entity (you could call it a `Position`). All reviews are done for the `Position`, not the `Job` or `User`. You can get job and user details by JOINing it. You could also have job and user details copied into `Candidacies` upon hiring, so that you keep history of what was on the hiring agreement even though the `Job` / `User` was altered (or removed) later.